# Grep (fgrep) bash exact match end of line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have the below example file

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /home/abid/Testing/FileNamesTest/apersand $ file
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /home/abid/Testing/FileNamesTest/file[with square brackets]
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /home/abid/Testing/FileNamesTest/~$tempfile
017a3635ccb76250b2036d6aea330c80  /home/abid/Testing/FileNamesTest/FileThree
217a3635ccb76250b2036d6aea330c80  /home/abid/Testing/FileNamesTest/FileThreeDays
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /home/abid/Testing/FileNamesTest/single quote's
```

I want to grep the last part of the file (the file name) but I'm after an exact match for the last part of the line (the file name)

```
grep FileThree$ files.md5
017a3635ccb76250b2036d6aea330c80  /home/abid/Testing/FileNamesTest/FileThree
```

gives back an exact match and doesnt find "FileThreeDays" which is what I'm after but because some of the file names contains square brackets it I'm having to use grep -F or fgrep.  However using fgrep like the above doesnt work it returns nothing.

How can I exact match the last part of the line using fgrep whilst still honoring the special characters above ~ / $ / ' / [ ]  etc...or any other method using maybe awk...

Further....

using fgrep withou return both these files I only want an exact match (using the use of the $ above with grep), but $ with fgrep doesnt return anything.

```
 grep -F FileThree files.md5
017a3635ccb76250b2036d6aea330c80  /home/abid/Testing/FileNamesTest/FileThree
217a3635ccb76250b2036d6aea330c80  /home/abid/Testing/FileNamesTest/FileThreeDays
```

Comment: You're probably best off using regular grep and escaping the characters you need to escape using \. I posted an alternative answer below.

Comment: This would work for your sample file above: `fgrep -w FileThree files.md5`.  It would break if you'd also have a directory named `FileThree`.  Still, `-w` can make your life simpler in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell all the details from your question, but it sounds like you can use grep and just escape the special characters: `grep 'File\[Three\]Days$'`

If you want to use `fgrep`, though, you can use some `tr` tricks to help you. If all you want is the filename (without the directory name), you can do something like

```
cat files.md5 | tr '/' '\n' | fgrep FileThreeDays
```

That `tr` command replaces slashes with newlines, so it will put each filename on its own line. That means that `fgrep` will only find the filename when it searches for FileThreeDays.

If you want the full filename with directory, it's a little trickier, but a similar approach will work. Assuming that there's always a double space between the SHA and the filename, and that there aren't any filenames with double spaces or tab characters in them, you can try something like this:

```
sed 's/  /\t' files.md5 | tr '\t' '\n' | fgrep FileThreeDays
```

That `sed` command converts the double spaces to tabs. The `tr` command turns those tabs into newlines (the same trick as above).

Comment: unfortunately i'm going to be doing this for millions of files and I have noticed files with double spaces.  I will need the md5 as well so dont think the first approach would work.  Also not sure if escaping is an option as I will have to script this somehow due to the number of files involved

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '{$1="";print}' file
```

`$1=""` cuts the first column to an empty string, and `print` prints the modified line - which only contains the filename now.

However, this leaves a blank space at the start of each line. If you care about it and want to remove it, set the output field separator to an empty string:

```
awk '{$1="";print}' OFS="" file
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I need the whole line as I need the md5 from the filename

Comment: Then you want `grep -F` (fixed-strings). You don't need to quote special chars when using `-F`

Comment: see above for the issue with grep -F

Comment: Check this if you want a script to escape regex metacharacters reliably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed You can use that also for grep. Is this what you are looking for?